# How to Remove particular Tab dynamically in Tabview

Tags: nativescript, tabview

All I have 5 Tab on my screen and I want to remove Tab which is at Index 3.  Please help me to solve this. I am using Nativescript with Javascript.I tried with "Visibility" but for TabViewItem  Visibility is not working.

I expect something that remove my 4th tab so I will have 4 Tab on my screen

Comment: When you want to remove the tabs, get the `items` attribute of TabView which is array of tabs, filter and update the `items` array without the tab item.